# what is the reason to hide a method with the new keyword, when only returning base.method?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I found the following code snippet in the DbSet Class of the EntityFramework:

```
public new Type GetType()
{
  return base.GetType();
}
```

I have no idea why the base method is hidden, all the base classes have the method implemented calling base.

This is `object.GetType()`:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public extern Type GetType();
```

This is in the `DbQuery` class:

```
/// <inheritdoc />
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1024:UsePropertiesWhereAppropriate")]
public new Type GetType()
{
  return base.GetType();
}
```

And this is in the `DbSet` (`DbSet<TEntity> : DbQuery<TEntity>`) class:

```
/// <inheritdoc />
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1024:UsePropertiesWhereAppropriate")]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public new Type GetType()
{
  return base.GetType();
}
```

Why or when would you use the `new` keyword and then call the base implementation?

Comment: The only purpose I see is to hide it from the Intellisense (`EditorBrowsable` attribute). I have no idea why it's needed though.

Comment: @IvanStoev I also thought about that, but why is it in both the `DbQuery` and the `DbSet` class?

Comment: Good question :) Redundant of course, could be forgotten during the refactoring etc. The whole need of these overloads/overrides is a mystery - you can see one and the same region called `Hidden Object methods` copy/pasted in many places in the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Infrastructure/DbQuery.cs) with no additional comment *why* is that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider the alternatives.

1. Don't override or new anything

   Problem: There's no code on which to apply attributes.
2. Just override it

   Problem: `GetType` is not virtual.

So you're left using `new` with a call to `base`.

The real question is what is so important about `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` that they went to all this trouble? My only guess is that they felt that developers would confuse `GetType` with [`ElementType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery.elementtype(v=vs.113).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery.ElementType) in intellisense.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now. I'm just curious now on why they added the same piece of code in `DbSet` again that was already in `DbQuery`.

Answer (score 2):

I think one reason you would use the new keyword is when you want to change the access modifier. If your method is protected in the base class you can make it public in your child class using the new keyword.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, I'm afraid. The base class' `GetType` is also public as you can see in the code I posted.